# Android Kotlin Hiding not Included ProgressBar with Text using Binding Variables not Hiding the Layout

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, android-databinding

I'm coding an Android studio app in Kotlin using the new Binding variable approach.

When I Include a Layout in my fragment, I cannot get the entire layout to be hidden.  The layout has a progress bar and test.  I can hide the progress bar, but the text stays and the "overlay" remain.  Preventing the user from interacting with the fragment below.

If I use just a `progressBar`, it works ok.  Its just not the look I want and it doesn't block activity with the background.

My quesiton is, how do I hide the enteire included-layout?

I want to do somethng like:

```
binding.progressBarWText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
...
binding.progressBarWText.visibility = View.GONE
```

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pbText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryColor"
        android:text="Processing ..."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_series_list"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switch_favoriteSeries"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="@string/favoriteSeries"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/seriesList_RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/switch_favoriteSeries" />

<!--        <ProgressBar-->
<!--            android:id="@+id/progressBarWText"-->
<!--            android:layout_width="0dp"-->
<!--            android:layout_height="0dp"-->
<!--            android:visibility="gone"-->
<!--            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
<!--            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
<!--            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
<!--            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->

        <include
            android:id="@+id/progressBarWText"
            layout="@layout/progress_bar_with_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my fragment

```
            binding.progressBarWText.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            binding.progressBarWText.pbText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

...

```
            binding.progressBarWText.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.progressBarWText.pbText.visibility = View.GONE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the entire included layout, e.g the `<include>` tag with id `progressBarWText`, you can call `binding.progressBarWText.root.visibility = View.GONE`.